# Iterating a file over all characters in C++

Tags: c++, file

Newb question: what is the best way to get a char iterator over a text file?

I tried:

```
std::fstream csvSource (fileName);

auto aChar = csvSource.begin();
while (aChar != csvSource.end())
{
  switch (*aChar)
  {
  case '"':
  //and so on
```

but the compiler complains that `fstream` doesn't have a begin method.

Note, that I can't do it line-by-line, because newline characters that are within quotes are treated differently (literaly) than the other new line characters.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `>>` operator from the `ifstream` class

```
std::ifstream csvSource (fileName);

csvSource >> noskipws;
char c;
while (csvSource>>c)
{
  switch (c)
  {
  case '"':
  //and so on
```

If you don't want to do fancy stuff with your iterators, that's the simplest way

Comment: That won't work, it skips whitespace (see OP's comment on processing newlines).

Comment: You can use a manipulator to override skipping whitespace, although that cuts down on simplicity

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use iterators, your best bet is [istreambuf_iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/istreambuf_iterator/) which is more optimal than `istream_iterator` when iterating chars.

Is there any particular reason though why you need to use iterators at all? They are there for the benefit of when you want to invoke an algorithm that requires them. But that isn't the case here as you are just looping.

You could just read in a char with `get()`. This might be better than operator>> which does a formatted read in, and will skip whitespace (which you might not want) unless you set `skipws` flag to false (I think it's `noskipws`) and may well be slightly less efficient.

Comment: The code borrowed from another SO question was using string iterators, that's all. Is it better to use get() or `>>` operator?

Comment: @Grzenio `get` fetches a single unformatted character, `operator>>` performs a formatted read, which if its operand is of type `char` will read a single character, skipping whitespaces. So, if you want to read a single character and you don't have any particular need for formatting, I'd recommend using `get`.

Comment: operator>> will skip whitespace unless you set a particular flag and is likely to be less efficient than a straightforward get().

istream(buf)_iterators are there for the benefit of when you need to put them into algorithms that require them, but in your case you are just looping so don't really have any need for them.

Comment: Why is `istreambuf_iterator` more optimal than `istream_iterator` ( when iterating chars)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `std::istreambuf_iterator` as

```
#include <iterator>   //for std::istreambuf_iterator
#include <algorithm> //for std::for_each

std:: istreambuf_iterator<char> begin(csvSource), end;
std::for_each(begin, end, [](char c)
             {
                  switch(c)
                  {
                        //your cases and code
                  }
             });
```

Or you can simply write `csvSource >> c` to read char-by-char. Both approaches are good. Which one to use, depends on situation.

Comment: You can't use `>>`, that's formatted input and skips whitespace (which the OP is interested in).

Answer (score 0):

Try [std::istream_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator). A very low level approach using raw loops could look like this:

```
std::fstream csvSource (fileName);
typedef std::istream_iterator<char> CharIter;
for (CharIter it(csvSource); it != CharIter(); ++it)
{
  /* process *it */
  char c = *it;
  doSomething(c);
}
```

You can also use those iterators in all standard algorithms and handcrafted algorithms, which is preferable to raw loops. For example, to print all characters in the file to `std::cout` you can use

```
std::copy(CharIter{csvSource}, CarIter{}, std::ostream_iterator(std::cout));
```

Comment: Please show us *how* you want to process each char. How would you `std::cout << each_single_char` via `it` ?

Comment: The user explicitly asked for getting the iterator, so I assumed they know to dereferece it. But I added some example code to show you how to work with the chars manually in the loop and in algorithms.